# The label and value in a pdf created using PdfStamper are not aligned properly

Tags: java, itext, pdf-reader, pdfstamper

I am trying to create a PDF file using PDFStamper.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(file));        
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);
    AcroFields acroForm = stamper.getAcroFields();              
    acroForm.setField("Address", "Street 10");
    acroForm.setFieldProperty("Address", "setfflags",
                                      PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

Here the field name is Address and value is Street 10.

When I view the pdf the Label Address and its value is not aligned properly.

**The value is aligned a bit lower than the label. When I click on the value it slides and changes its position upwards.**

Sorry for my weird explanation.

Can some one tell how do I make my text in alignement with the label.

Comment: There has never been a clear definition of the baseline of a field in a PDF form. Its position has been changed in-between versions of Acrobat as well as in-between versions of iText. Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: By the way: changing the property to read-only isn't necessary if you're flattening the form anyway.